# Rails STI design issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance, sti

I am working a side project where a user can have multiple clients. Those client can be of type Person or Business.

I was leaning toward the idea to using STI but I am not sure whether this is the right way to go since my models will not share the same attributes.

For instance a Business has a legal_form where a Person might have a marital_status.

Is it ok to use STI in this particular case or (2nd question) is there any way to allow rails to use separate tables for each types.

Answer (score 1):

STI is like inheritance in ruby. You can use it if you have *parent* and *children* and they share a lot of attributes and data. If `Person` and `Business` share a lot you can use it. Otherwise I'd recommend you use [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

> A slightly more advanced twist on associations is the polymorphic
>   association. With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more
>   than one other model, on a single association. For example, you might
>   have a picture model that belongs to either an employee model or a
>   product model. Here's how this could be declared:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

[image]

I [don't really like](https://about.futurelearn.com/blog/refactoring-rails-sti/) STI and I'd recommend you try to use Polymorphic Associations.

**A common problem with STI**

> A common problem with STI is that, over time, more types get added to
>   that table, and it grows more and more columns, and the records in the
>   table have less and less in common with one another. Each type of
>   record uses some subset of the table’s columns, and none uses all of
>   them, so you end up with a very sparsely populated table. Those types
>   create costs for one another: when you query for articles, you must
>   remember to filter out all the other types of values and to only
>   select columns relevant to articles, or else pay a huge performance
>   cost. You reproduce a lot of work the database would do for you, if
>   you only had each data type in its own table.

Comment: I have considered using Polymorphic Associations but I don't know how I should organise it. I already created 3 models (with 3 tables) Client, Business and Person. My ultimate goal would be to have a Clients controller from which I could call for a list of all the Clients whether they are  Business or Person.

Comment: @makabde yes, where a problem is? :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I would go for the polymorphic association would this be correct

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cliental, polymorphic: true
end

class Business < ActionRecord::Base
  # Here I am using has_one because I do not want to have duplicates
  has_one :client, as: :cliental
end

 class Person < ActionRecord::Base
  # Here I am using has_one because I do not want to have duplicates
  has_one :client, as: :cliental
end
```

And later I would like to do the following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many clients
  has_many businesses, through: :client
  has_many people, through: :client
end
```